# How wide should the word space after nobiliary particles be? (von, de la, …)

Tags: typography, typesetting

Is it preferable to write a thin space after nobiliary particles (von, de la, …)?

Does for example `Miguel de\,Cervantes y\,Saavedra` look better than the standard width spaced equivalent?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have the answer for French typography (and one of the nobiliary particles you quote is French, so…): the spaces preceding and following nobiliary particles should be regular spaces (the canonical reference being the *[Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie Nationale](http://www.amazon.fr/Lexique-regles-typographiques-lImprimerie-Nationale/dp/2743304820)*).

I don't know if it holds in other languages, including English, but it would definitely make sense… and cause less disruption to the flow of text.

Comment: Alright then, I guess it applies anyway—as long as the names are French, at least. :) Thank you.

Comment: I'd have to concur. I've never come across special treatment for this case.